# Is this a good model for Repeated Measures Mancova?

Tags: repeated-measures, categorical-encoding, mancova

I surveyed 400 participants and each participant received 8 images to analyze, each image with the manipulation of 3 factors (A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC, Control - no changes). Then, they answered the same question for each image, choosing one option of 4 (W, X, Y, Z).
I am analyzing the data in SPSS.  I used the Repeated Measures Mancova, including my IVs (A, B, C) as dummy variables (0 - not applied, 1 - applied).  Then, I included my DVs (A_W, B_W, C_W, AB_W, AC_W, BC_W, ABC_W, Control_W...repeating for X, Y, and Z) also as dummy variables (0 - option not chosen and 1 - option chosen).  My covariates are age, gender, and duration.
I would like to know if this is a good model to analyze this data.